# Microsoft Graph Beta Channel API giving 500 Error while creating private channels

Tags: postman, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Till yesterday  I was able to create private channels through Beta Channel API. Suddenly today its giving 500 Error(Internal server Error). I am passing token in headers and Json also correctly.
Does anyone also facing the same issue.

API which I am executing in Postman

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamid}/channels](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bteamid%7D/channels)

```
{
 "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Teams.Core.channel",
 "membershipType": "private",
 "displayName": "My First Private Channel",
 "description": "This is my first private channels",
 "members":
    [
       {
          "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
          "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('92fb4ef2-3ad8-4316-a6f2-2925afcb7d75')",
          "roles":["owner"]
       }
    ]
}
```